# APT-Mirror Stuck on downloading index files "Downloading 270 index files using 20 threads"

Tags: apt, updates, repository, proxy

I get the following output after a clean install of apt-mirror and running  as root:

Downloading 270 index files using 20 threads
[20] ...

Nothing seems to happen after waiting a couple minutes. This process should be very quick. Viewing the log at /var/apt-mirror/var/index-log.0it shows that it is trying to reach my corporate proxy but times out.

I can ping my proxy and I can download from an online repo using apt install through my corporate proxy. It just doesn't work with apt-mirror

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that `apt-mirror` uses `wget` to retrieve index files, which is the first step of running `apt-mirror`. I have to include the following in my `/etc/wgetrc` file

```
https_proxy = http://myproxyIP:portnumber/
http_proxy = http://myproxyIP:portnumber/
ftp_proxy = http://myproxyIP:portnumber/
```

This resolved my issue.